# Javascript - Add Array of Objects to existing Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I have a Customer with Apples, I have an  `Api Controller` that takes an `Object Customer` as a parameter, and updates the existing one in the database with these new Apples:

```
[HttpPut("Update")]
    public async void Put([FromBody]Customer customer)
    {
        await _repository.UpdateCustomer(customer);
    }
```

Using Javascript, I want to add these new Apples to my current `List` of Apples in the Customer. From reading on SO it should look something like:

```
addApplesToCustomer_method: function () {
        var updatedCustomer = this.currentCustomer;
        Array.prototype.push.apply(updatedCustomer.apples, this.selectedApples);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/customer/update',
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                customer: updatedCustomer
            }),
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error: ' + textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

`currentCustomer` is the customer we want to update. `selectedApples` is the new `List` of Apples we want to add to our Customers existing `Array` of Apples.

The above however does not even run since I added the `Array.prototype.push.apply(updatedCustomer.apples, this.selectedApples)` but it doesnt give me an error either. Just nothing happens. If I go back to sending the Customer and Apples seperately to my Controller it works, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Sounds like you need [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `spread` syntax.

```
updatedCustomer.apples.push(...this.selectedApples);
```

> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string
>   to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function
>   calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object
>   expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs
>   (for object literals) are expected.

Comment: what do the dots represent?

Comment: Here is provided a lot of examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: @Green_qaue, Just use a `condition` : `if(arr==null) updatedCustomer.apples=[] else updatedCustomer.apples.push(...this.selectedApples);`

Answer (score 0):

How about just pushing the object onto the array with`Array.push(object)`

```
let objectArray = []

let apple = {
  name: 'Apple',
  size: 'medium'
}

let orange = {
  name: 'Orange',
  size: 'large'
}

// Create an initial list with apples
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  objectArray.push(apple)
}

// Now add an orange to that list
objectArray.push(orange)

// The resulting array contains 10 apples, 1 orange.
console.log(objectArray)
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j7kcjjqh/

(Inspect the console to see the result)